# Android APP after ADMOB mediation

Tags: android, admob

I have added mediation and its related SDKs into my APK. I have released my APK in all stores. I am worried about the old version which may get the ADs from the mediated AD networks. In that case my old versions will crash ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old version of your app (without mediation) will not request ad from any network for which it doesn't have libraries. So it will not crash.

Comment: Thanks I have found that and published it.